# How to implement a similar of photoshop's "patch tool" function?

Tags: image, delphi, image-processing, opencv, photoshop

I have to automatically remove a barcode in a T-Shirt image, like the attached file:

[barcode http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/2888/codel.jpg](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/2888/codel.jpg)

I know I can do it manually in photoshop using the function "patch tool" that replaces the cropped area by image in the surrounded area but I need to either implement a code for that or get an SDK in Delphi to support this process automatically by passing to the function the (X,Y) points of the edges of the barcode.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If someone has to figure out the coordinates anyway, does it take more work just to use that in Photoshop to do it manually? I mean... someone must sift through all those photos and find those coordinates anyway, right?

Comment: Can you automate it in Photoshop? That is can you formulate the problem so that the operation to remove the tag is always the same? I would automate the command I am sending to Photoshop. You will need to use an image editing library and you may as well use Photoshop.

Comment: I need to do this for a batch work inside my aplication that detects the barcode. I do have the barcode coordinates from all images from a previous detection algorithm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you already have the barcode position, you could generate a mask automagically  and perform a [**Navier-Stokes Image Restoration**.](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~mbertalmio/final-cvpr.pdf)

Example in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: @Marjan Yep. It's a nice feature of Mathematica. See for example here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inpaint.html

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! After your answer, I discover that OpenCV has an implementation of this method, and this worked very fine for me! Thanks man!

Comment: Another inpainting method is from [Telea03] that you can find here, and openCV has as well an implementation of this method...
http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/2702346/an-image-inpainting-technique-based-on-the-fast-marching-method